# Rationals in R and deformation retract of set

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, geometric-topology

Problem:
Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a deformation retract of an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Approach: Enumerate rationals by $q_1,q_2,q_3...$ For each $i$, choose an open set $U_i$ of $q_i$ that deformation retracts onto $U_i$ and such that $U_i\cap U_j= \varnothing$. Put $U=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i$. Then $U$ deformation retracts to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Is this proof right?

Comment: Is it possible for a connected set to deformation retract to a disconnected set?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Henderson $U$ is not connected

Comment: You didn't answer my question, but I am going to assume that your answer is "no".  The set $U$, being open in $\mathbb{R}$, is made up of a countable number of disjoint open intervals.  Pick one such interval, say $I_j$.   Is $I_j$ connected?  Is $\mathbb{Q}\cap I_j$ connected?

Comment: Since your $U_i$ contains many $q_j$'s (among which $q_i$), your $U_i$'s cannot be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: @AnneBauval But  $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff space.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I see thanks! what if weaken deformation retract to just 'retract'?

Comment: I maintain that your attempt is flawed. Hausdorff deals with 2 points, not an infinite set of points.

Comment: Continuous maps preserve connectedness, no?  And retractions are continuous, yes?  What do you conclude from that?

Answer (score 0):

Not all $U_i$ can be pairwise disjoint in your construction. That is because each $U_i$ contains more than $1$ rational.

Moreover $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be a retract of any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. One of the reasons is that retractions are quotient maps. And quotient maps preserve local connectedness. And open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are locally connected while $\mathbb{Q}$ is not.